# multivariate function multiplied by its partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$g\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\mathbf{k}\right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{k} $$

Could somebody explain this step? I believe it is chain rule but I am slightly lost in the jump.

Answer (score 1):

The $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\cdot \vec{i} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \cdot \vec{j} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \cdot \vec{k}$$
is called the [gradient](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/gradient-and-directional-derivatives/v/gradient) of a function. It is a vector contains partial derivatives as components.

So, your question was, why this equality holds $$g\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (\frac{1}{2}g^2)}{\partial x}?$$

Let's find the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}g^2$:
$$
\frac{\partial (\frac{1}{2}g^2)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (\frac{1}{2}g^2)}{\partial g} \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=g \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
$$
(as you have mentioned, chain rule is useful here). And we are done!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking this is an application of the chain rule.  It's a bit easier to see going right to left.  Looking just at the first term:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{i} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g^2\mathbf{i} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot g\cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathbf{i} = g\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathbf{i}.$$  Doing the same thing for each of the terms gives us
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{1}{2}g^2\right)\mathbf{k} &=g\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathbf{i} + g\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\mathbf{j} + g\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\mathbf{k}\\
&=g\left[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\mathbf{k}\right].
\end{align}